# Android Parse notification issues

Tags: java, android, service, parse-platform, broadcastreceiver

I have a Parse notification in my app. If I open my app. then it will receive the notification.
If I restart my phone. No notification will be received, until I open my app.

My question is:

How Can I initiate / run, my ParsePushBroadcastReceiver whenever the phone has been restarted. or how can I make this Receiver to be always running even if user close the app / kill the app ?

I though by adding android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED would work. but it don't

Here is my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name="com.my.app.core.MyParseReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.my.app" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

My Class

```
....
public class MyParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive Called");

        if (intent == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
        } 
        else {
            // Parse push message and handle accordingly
            Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent data => " + intent.toString());
        }

    }//end onReceive



    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it but you could make an onBacKeyPressed() method and just make it look like the app has been killed.